# What is the best practice where should I store the variables in single-node multi-GPU training?

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am new to distributing training. I have seen many tutorials about that and most of them just say, store the variables in the cpu without any more benchmark.

So can I store the variables in the GPU:0? even store a copy in each GPU? What is the best practice for this?